# android bg prob

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add a background to my android project. Heres the code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backround="@drawable/awesome_face">

</RelativeLayout>
```

I spelled everything out correct but when i go into my graphical layout after saving and nothing shows up. Furthermore after i cleaned the project I now have an error on the

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

saying "no resource identifier found for attribute background in package 'android'" Anyone have ideas?

Comment: background with a 'g' in the layout definition.

Comment: And a RelativeLayout has no property 'orientation'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like  ChristopheCVB said, your backgroud tag is missing a G.

```
android:backGround="@drawable/awesome_face">
```

Comment: Note that the capitalization is for emphasis (I assume), the G should really be lowercase in your manifest.

Comment: wow im an idiot. im still getting used to english. my home lanuage is swedish